# Paypal webhooks and subscription expiration dates

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

I'm listening for the `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` event and everything gets stored in my backend. This event contains a property called `next_billing_time`, which is all good. Then whenever a user makes a payment to that subscription ID it is shown in the `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED` event, this event however has no `next_billing_time` property. My question is, how do I keep track of the new billing time after payment is made? Do I have to use the old `next_billing_time` and calculate that manually?

Answer (score 2):

The simplest design is to go off PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED. Use it to mark a subscription good for 1 month or whatever term (maybe a day of grace time), and if you don't receive a new PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED soon enough, consider the subscription lapsed on your end.